# Find all the values of the parameter $c$ for which the inequality has atleast one solution.

Tags: inequality, quadratics

Find all the values of the parameter $c$ for which the inequality has atleast one solution.
$$1+\log_2(2x^2+2x+\frac{7}{2})\geq\log_2(cx^2+c)$$

---

First i checked the domain of the inequality,
$2x^2+2x+\frac{7}{2}>0$ and $cx^2+c>0$
First inequality will always be positive for $x\in R$ because its discriminant is negative.And second inequality will be positive provided $c$ is positive.
Then i simplified the given inequality.
$$1+\log_2(2x^2+2x+\frac{7}{2})\geq\log_2(cx^2+c)$$
$4x^2+4x+7\geq cx^2+c$
$(4-c)x^2+4 x+(7-c)\geq 0$
In order to have no solution of the above inequality,we should have discriminant $\geq 0$ and in order to have atleast one solution of the above inequality,we should have discriminant $<0$
$16-4(4-c)(7-c)<0$
$c^2-11c+24>0$ gives me $c\in (-\infty,3)\cup(8,\infty)$
But the answer given is $0<c\leq 8$.I dont know where i am wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly we require $c>0$ for the second log to be real.

Now considering your inequality $$(4-c)x^2+4x+(7-c)\geq0$$

If $c<4$ there will always be at least one solution to the inequality aince the curve is a positive quadratic.

If $c>4$, we require that the discriminant of this negative quadratic to be positive or equal to zero so that the curve does not lie entirely below the $x$ axis.

Therefore $$16-4(4-c)(7-c)\geq0$$
$$\Rightarrow (c-3)(c-8)\leq 0$$
$$\Rightarrow 3\leq c\leq8$$
Hence the requirement for $c$, when we combine these results, is $$0<c\leq8$$

Comment: Nice..............+1@David Quinn

Comment: Thank you @Bhaskara-III and a Happy New Year to you

Comment: For a positive quadratic, there will always be points above the x axis so the inequality will always be satisfied by at least one x

Comment: I got it,thank you very much and a very Happy New Year to you.

Comment: You're welcome, and a Happy New Year to you too!

Answer (score 0):

No for one solution discriminant has to be equal to $0$ and for two solutions its $<,>0$ as $log(z)=log(x)+i\theta$ where $|z|=x,\theta$ is its argument. If its real solutions then discriminant is $>0$. Atleast one means its parabola with vertex at $X-axis$ and two means parabola witg two points of intersection on X-axis. Answer to your comment $(c-3)(c-8)>0$ so c(0,8]$

Comment: Can you prove $0<c\leq 8$?

Comment: You have to do $c^2-11c+24>=0$

Comment: You have done it for $<0$

Comment: Then also,answer will come $3<c<8$ not $0<c\leq 8$

Comment: See if botg are negative then  also it is positive thats the catch now can you see why its $(0,8]$